# AngularJS zebra striping for table with hidden rows

Tags: jquery, angularjs, css

I am trying to add zebra stripe to a table which has hidden rows (uses `ng-hide` to hide). Because angular only hides the rows, whether I use css3 or jQuery to strip, the coloring is not correct, you can see the sample below.

Row 3 is hidden, Row 2 and Row 4 are having same color.

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zXKXyJhazET6qpUhuP8V?p=preview).

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach would be to use ng-if, instead of ng-hide.  This would prevent the element from being created, rather than hiding it.  Then the css would work as expected.

[Here is a working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/LZqCkAYtohdk0cPvs1NB)

Comment: Thanks so much for timely solution.

Comment: The link to the Plnkr is dead.